# remove Item From List in angular

Tags: javascript

I have this list :

```
0: {id: 1, scoreValue: 33, coinValue: 1}
1: {id: 2, coinValue: 41, scoreValue: 1}
2: {id: 3, scoreValue: 33, coinValue: 0}
3: {id: 3, coinValue: 41, scoreValue: 33}
4: {id: 3, coinValue: 44, scoreValue: 33}
```

and I need to remove the item from this list with this code:

```
        let model = {} as EdiltListModel;
        let find = this.editListModel.find(x => x.id === id);

        if (find !== undefined) {
            model.id = find.id;
            model.scoreValue = parseInt($event.target.value);
            model.coinValue = coinValue;
            const index = this.editListModel.findIndex(x => x.id = find.id);
            this.editListModel = this.editListModel.slice(index, 1);
        } else {
            model.id = id;
            model.scoreValue = parseInt($event.target.value);
            model.coinValue = parseInt(coinValue);
        }
        this.editListModel.push(model);
```

but it not remove that item. How can I remove item from this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.editListModel = this.editListModel.slice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). This removes the items.

```
this.editListModel.splice(index, 1);
```

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes a copy from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The deleting logic can be done with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
You will archive that as follows.

```
this.editListModel = this.editListModel.filter(model => model.id != id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove item by using `filter` method

```
this.editListModel = this.editListModel.filter(item => item.id !== find.id);
```

Comment: why first find `index` when you can filter by `id` itself?